# Is there any easy way within Java to prefix one string onto multiple other strings?

Tags: java, string

Does anybody know if there is any easy way within Java to prefix one string onto multiple other strings?

For example, if I have the following snippet of Java code ;

```
String              includeDir = "/usr/local/boost-1.52.0/include";

ArrayList<String>   filenamesRelative = new ArrayList<String>(),
                    filenamesAbsolute = new ArrayList<String>();


filenamesRelative.add("/boost/aligned_storage.hpp");
filenamesRelative.add("/boost/any.hpp");
```

I would like to be able to prefix the value of the variable 'includeDir', i.e. "/usr/local/boost-1.52.0/include", onto the front of each value in the ArrayList filenamesRelative.

Ideally, I would like to be able to do something like the following ;

```
filenameAbsolute = filenamesRelative.prefixAll(includeDir);
```

I don't necessarily have to use ArrayLists in the solution; I have just used them above for illustrative purposes.

From memory, you can do something like this rather easily in C++ using the STL, however my current working knowledge of Java isn't all that good unfortunately :(

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Are you against just using a loop?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308393/how-do-i-prefix-a-string-to-each-element-in-an-array-of-strings

Answer (score 3):

I dont know of a method in the API. but its so simple just create your own. Something like:

```
List<String> filenameAbsolute = new ArrayList<String>();

for ( String file: filenamesRelative ) {
    filenameAbsolute.add(prefix + file);
}
```

Comment: My current solution is very similar to the one you have proposed; I just thought there might have been a slightly more straight forward way to solve this problem. I'm starting to feel that the C++ STL has 'coloured' my thinking with regard to problems like this. Thanks for your solution all the same however.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
ArrayList<String> prefixAll(ArrayList<String> filenamesRelative)
{
    ArrayList<String> filenamesAbsolute = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    String includeDir = "/usr/local/boost-1.52.0/include";

    for ( String file: filenamesRelative ) {
       filenameAbsolute.add(includeDir + file);
    }//for

    return filenameAbsolute;
}//prefixAll()
```

Comment: you're adding one more copy of each string into the same arraylist

Comment: ok, why are you returning the same list that was an argument to method?