# How to append prefix to each string in a list after mapping?

Tags: java

I need to append a prefix "ROLE_" to each string collected after mapping with string in an object. I have done this in two steps as showin in method mappedListWithPrefix:

```
class MyClass {

String uid;

}

////////

List<String> mappedListWithPrefix(List<MyClass> list) {

  List<String> op = list.stream().map(MyClass::getUid).collect(Collectors.toList());//step 1
  op.replaceAll(s -> "ROLE_"+s);//step 2

  return op;
}
```

Is there a way to do this in a single step, without using a second list, somewhat like map( "ROLE_"+MyClass::getUid) ? (Pls note this is just to convey idea, this mapping wont wrk)

Comment: in your stream replace `My::getUid` with `s -> "ROLE_" + s.getUid()`

Comment: This also [How do I prefix a String to each element in an array of Strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308393/how-do-i-prefix-a-string-to-each-element-in-an-array-of-strings)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can *either* add a second `map` step:

```
List<String> op = list.stream()
   .map(MyClass::getUid)
   .map(s -> "ROLE_" + s)
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

*or* just do both operations in one `map` call:

```
List<String> op = list.stream()
   .map(o -> "ROLE_" + o.getUid())
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Which one to pick is mostly down to personal preference.

Comment: Fun, but useless trivia: you can replace the second map call in the first code block with `.map("ROLE_"::concat)`, which does the same thing but is a bit harder to read and not very intuitive.